# CSS Completely Breaks Wordpress Pagelines Site?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, pagelines, pagelines-framework

I'm using the [Pagelines Theme](http://www.pagelines.com/wiki/How_to_Use_the_Custom_Code_Settings) for [a site](http://www.crankhousecycles.com), and I put custom CSS in the custom CSS field. Long story short, I broke the entire site, and the CSS is stored in the database.

When loading the page there is absolutely nothing. A blank head tag and a blank body tag.

Firstly, how is this possible, and secondly, does anyone know how to exclude the dynamic.css stylesheet stored in a database with just the database login info, but without cpanel access?

Comment: Can you connect to the FTP and see if the files are still there ? Do you have made any backup before installing the theme ?

Comment: Yeah, I FTPed and everything is identical. I'm pretty sure it's related to the Custom CSS which is stored in the database because I was editing the file, saved it to check how it looked, and the site was down since then.

Comment: Doesn't look like it is the css. There is no html structure/output for your site, you see.

Comment: Many hosts will configure your default server behavior to suppress error messages (for security purposes).  I suspect you're throwing some sort of error before the page has a chance to render.  While it may appear that you have a blank head and body tag, you actually don't. (The developer tools are showing those, but the actual page source is empty). If you have access to your error logs I would inspect those for the actual issue.

Comment: @Omega, you're right. I could have sworn it was the CSS but I guess not. I ruled it out.

Comment: @JaredCobb, good call. I turned on Wordpress DEBUG mode, but it doesn't spit anything out in a browser or in the debug.log file. The host is Godaddy. Thoughts?

Comment: @ElijahMurray Getting `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)` now, best to speak to your hosting to see if theres any issues with them. Read this http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/wordpress-whats-happening-need-help/ also.

Comment: @ElijahMurray Yes, I would contact GoDaddy support and ask them how you can view / access the "error logs" for your apache/php server.  They should understand what you need.  They most likely have an interface in your admin panel to check error logs.  The reason the debug mode doesn't give you anything is because something at a lower level is failing, preventing it from even getting to the debug code. Sorry I can't direct you to the log location, but I've never used GoDaddy.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I just backed up the DB and core files and rebuilt the site.

Answer (score 0):

Check your functions.php to ensure there are no spaces before or after the opening and closing php tags.